# Concentration bound for square of sum of Rademacher random varialbes

Tags: probability, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

For $i\in[n]$ let us define iid random variables $u_i\sim \text{Unif}(\{-1,1\})$, i.e. $Pr(u_i=1)=Pr(u_i=-1)=1/2$. Also let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n u_i$. My question is, how can we compute the concentration of $X^2$ around its mean $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$?

It is not hard to compute the mean by linearity of expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] =\sum_i \mathbb{E}[u_i^2] + \sum_{i\neq j} \mathbb{E}[u_i u_j ]$$ 
Because we always have $u_i^2=1$ we have $\mathbb{E}[u_i^2] = 1$ and also when $i\neq j$ then $u_i$ and $u_j$ are independent, we have $\mathbb{E}[u_i u_j] = \mathbb{E}[u_i] \mathbb{E}[u_j] = 0$ and therefore we can compute $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = n$.

However, computing the concentration seems a bit more tricky. It seems to me that if we define a new random variable $Y_{ij}=u_i u_j$ we can use Johnson's inequality because of little interaction between the $Y_{ij}$s. Any ideas on how to compute the concentration?

Comment: You have a subgaussian r.v. $X$. $X^2$ will be subexponential, and thus you'll have exponential-type concentration bounds.

Comment: Seee e.g. Section 3.1: https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This random variable $X^2 = q^* \boldsymbol{A} q$ where $\boldsymbol{A}$ is the matrix of all ones and $q$ is a Rademacher vector. A [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2475) by Roosta-Khorasani and Ascher gives tight concentration results for this variable when $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a generic positive semi definite matrix, and they apply here.

Rephrased, they prove that $$\mathbf{P}( | X^2 - n|>\epsilon n) < 2 e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}(\tfrac{\epsilon^2}{2} - \tfrac{\epsilon^3}{3})}.$$

Comment: This is quite overkill though :)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes; I couldn’t resist I was just using these results in a paper :)

Comment: coincidentally, this more powerful result is useful for another part of my calculations. thanks! @cdipaolo

Comment: is there a result for the theorem for that $A$ is not SPD?

Comment: in fact I don't want to preserve the trace, but the frobenius norm of the matrix $A$, what's the way to do that? should ask it in another post?

Comment: @kvphxga The Frobenius norm (squared) is the trace of $\boldsymbol{A^*A}$, so you can apply this bound using that fact. I don’t know of a result for trace concentration when the matrix is indefinite, (check out the Hanson-Wright inequality maybe?) but I suspect that you would need additional factors such as the Schatten-2 norm since you could have, say, the diagonal matrix with -100 and 100 and the zero matrix having the same trace, while the former RV would have much more variance.

Comment: @kvphxga Oh yes the Hanson-Wright inequality is exactly what you’re looking for. See this paper or Vershynin’s book Clement mentioned above: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ecp/1465315621

Comment: computing $A^* A$ is not really an option since I only have access to the matrix implicitly through vector products. Theorem 2.1 of the paper seems really relevant, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @kvphxga Yes but $q^* A^*Aq =\|Aq\|^2,$ so it can be done implicitly as well.